# Python code for class Not returning value

Tags: python, python-3.x

hello I Have a python code that keep giving me a error can some one look a it before i continue. this is for my python class to calculate the cell phone bill amount. I have This now But it's not returning a value

The economy plan includes $30 unlimited voice and text, 1 GB data for $10, and $6 for every GB over.

The normal plan includes $30 unlimited voice and text, 5 GB data for $30, and $4 for every GB over.

```
class cellphone:
    cost = 30
    due = 0
    amountGB = 0
    Total = 0

    def econPlan (self, gB, gbOver):
        self.cost = 30
        self.gB = 1
        self.gbOver = 6
        self.due = 0

        while amountGB >= self.gB:
            int(amountGB - self.gB)* self.gbOver
        return self.due

        while cPlan == Econ and amountGB >= self.gB:
            print ("$",self.due)

    def normPlan (self, gB, gbOver):
        self.cost = 30
        self.gB = 5
        self.gbOver = 4

        while amountGB >= self.gB:
            int(amountGB - self.gB)* self.gbOver
        return self.due

        while cPlan == Norm and amountGB >= self.gB:
            print ("$",self.due)






print (" Which Plan do you have: econ or norm?")
print (" Econ is $30 unlimited voice and text, 1 GB data for $10, and $6 for every GB over.")
print (" Norm is $30 unlimited voice and text, 5 GB data for $30, and $4 for every GB over.")

econ = cellphone.econPlan
norm = cellphone.normPlan
cellphone.cPlan = input ("So which plan do you have? >>")
if cellphone.cPlan == econ:
    print ("you have the Economy plan")

elif cellphone.cPlan == norm:
    print ("you have the Normal plan")

cellphone.amountGB = input ("how many GB did you used >>")
if cellphone.cPlan == "Econ":
    print (cellphone.due)
```

Comment: Post the error...

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: Where's `self`?

Comment: is self required

Comment: if block inside the class methods does not have proper indentation.

Comment: now  the error message is while ` amountGB >= self.gB:
NameError: name 'self' is not defined`

Comment: im not getting back a value.

Answer (score 0):

Self only exists within the methods. If you want to get the current value of a variable inside a method, call the method and return the variable.